# Background processing on a nodejs, mongodb and heroku stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, background-process

I'm writing a simple image upload site as a learning project.

It's written in nodejs, with mongodb and deployed onto Heroku cedar.

I'd like to implement a node script that runs say, once an hour, and applies the [reddit algorithm](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588) to images and stores the score against each image in mongodb.

How can I achieve this bearing in mind I am on heroku and have file system limitations? - Given the cedar architecture, it would be best to hand off to a separate worker, but if there's a faster/simpler/easier approach I'd be happy to hear it. The [heroku dev center article on workers/background jobs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) unfortunately doesn't list any tutorials yet for such a system.

My previous experience of background processing on heroku was with rails - so scheduled tasks add-on, + delayed_job and it's very straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extremely simple approach might utilize [setInterval](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) or [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). You might also want to [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) or [fork](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) a child process for this periodic processing.

Comment: Did it with node-cron as suggested. Thanks very much.